# How (or why) did Topology become so central to modern mathematics?

Tags: math-history

It is frequently said that topology is nowadays one of the central pillars of modern mathematics (ex. ["Because of its central place in a broad spectrum of mathematics"](http://www.math.columbia.edu/research/topology/))  The field has managed to blossom into a magnificently large field of mathematics, with tons of major applications into fields that even exist outside of math. How and why did this happen? Did topology originally come about as a way to solve unsolved problems at its time of origin, and later grew into what it is today? How has it become so central? (Side note: On a not too uncommon basis, topology seems to be one of the more 'quirky' fields of math.)

Comment: The way these fields usually develop is that a bunch of seemingly unrelated problems are solved.  Then, somebody says "hey, a lot of these problems follow a similar framework, maybe we can come up with a language which lets us talk about all of these things".  Someone then comes up with a mathematical structure that accomplishes this (in this case, a "topological space"), and then the study of that structure becomes an area of study.

Comment: A lot of the "questions" that were originally answered by topology were really a matter of justifying statements that were pretty much taken as true, but hadn't been rigorously proven.  For example, the convergence of a Fourier series to the associated function and the Jordan curve theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, even as a topologist, I wouldn't say that topology is any more central than a variety of other fields: analysis, algebra, and so on. Even then, there are areas of topology that really don't have any broad applications outside the subject itself: surgery theory, some of the very technical computations of the stable homotopy groups of spheres, etc. Topology at least appears in a variety of subjects, though, because it seems to be the suitable framework for a lot of math. In introductory real analysis, the intermediate value theorem is a statement about connectedness. The objects in differential geometry, analysis on manifolds, etc. are topological spaces (with a lot of extra structure). Even some constructions that aren't inherently topological, like (in)direct limits, naturality, often pop up first for students via algebraic topology classes.

Here's a more specific example. One of the most familiar examples of a cohomology theory is de Rham cohomology on a smooth manifold. This is a very concrete object: It's the space of solutions to a certain differential equation, modulo a space of 'trivial' solutions. Those equations always have a local solution; the problem is that those local solutions don't necessarily patch together to give a global solution. Cohomology groups are the obstructions to this patching construction. The same idea of obstructions to solving a global problem locally pops up in several different areas of math. Sheaf cohomology on a scheme, for example, is quite concretely a similar sort of obstruction, even though the Zariski topology is very different from the topology of a smooth manifold (or even CW-complex). There's another kind of cohomology defined for groups acting on modules, the connection being that abstract nonsense gives a connection between the group cohomology of $\pi$ and the (say, singular) cohomology of $K(\pi, 1)$. (I'm skipping over some nontrivial details here.) The same idea pops up in complex analysis (the Cousin problems, for example), various parts of physics, etc.; furthermore, extensions of this idea pop up in algebraic geometry, $K$-theory, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that limits and/or convergence are very important, because they allow you to approximate complicated objects by simple objects. For example, maybe you want to approximate a function by polynomials (taylor series) or by sinusoids (fourier analysis). From this standpoint, the important observation is that every topology induces a [convergence structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space), and topologies were invented first. Keywords: functional analysis, topological vector space.

A second reason is that (classical) differential geometry is based on the concept of a manifold, which is usually formulated in a way that makes reference to topological spaces. Indeed, at the bottom rung of the manifold ladder are "topological manifolds", which can be defined as topological spaces that look locally like $\mathbb{R}^n$, subject to the some further constraints.

A third reason is that the basic definitions of [homotopy theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category) make sense over general topological spaces; you don't need a manifold.

A fourth reason is the Zariski topology just so happens to be a topology.

A fifth reason is that often when you combine infinitely-many set-theoretic objects together in an interesting way, the resulting structure often ends up carrying a topology in a natural way. Look up "profinite completion of the integers." Its fundamental to modern number theory.

A sixth reason is that we can consider the [sheaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_%28mathematics%29) on a topological space, and $\mathbf{Set}$-valued sheaves are about as fundamental of an object as there is, because they always form a topos, which is a place where higher-order intuitionistic logic can be interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

In a very simplistic way we can think of it like this. Analysis means limit. Limit means continuity. Continuity means open set. And open sets mean topology. So in a way topology is the basis of analysis. Or at least that's how I see it.